# Classic ASP includes processing differently on my server than on local machine

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have a classic ASP website that is running perfectly on my Windows 2008 R2 VPS. In short, my problem is this:

On the server I have my DB connection defined in one include file (conn.asp) while I have my functions in another include file (functions.asp). I include the 'conn.asp' first, so the connection string exists before the functions of 'functions.asp' need it.

Once I download it to my local machine (Windows 7 64-bit) to do more development, suddenly the functions of 'functions.asp' throw errors that the connection string is empty. If I include 'conn.asp' within 'functions.asp' it works again, but I am trying to avoid endless levels of nested include files.

All I'm looking for is for my machine to process the include files the same as my server.

I presume it's an IIS 7.5 setting issue, but I've never had this problem before and don't know where to look and when I search for previous posts I must be searching for the wrong terms because I'm getting nothing useful.

If you can point me to a post somewhere that solves my problem, or to the settings themselves, I'd appreciate it.

Here's an example include string that I am using:

```
<!--#include file="conn.asp"-->
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if memory serves the ASP classic engine processes all the include files as it comes to them **before** it serves it to the browser. to troubleshot your issue, try placing a `response.write` inside of `conn.asp` to spit out the connection string and verify that the server is actually calling that include file.

Comment: Well, that wasn't it, but it led me to the problem. Apparently when downloading from the server one of my configuration files went corrupt. Doing what you recommended showed me what was missing and going to that file led me to downloading a new version and now it works.

Comment: I don't suppose you feel like marking this as the answer then? :D points for me!